# Oracle - constraint to check a value exists in another column

Tags: database, oracle

I need to check if the value of 'montant' exists in the column 'prix' of the table 'service' in order to add this value in the table.

This is what I tried so far :

`ALTER TABLE abonnement ADD CONSTRAINT montant_inclus CHECK(montant in (select prix from service));`

Here is the error I got :
 `ORA-02251: subquery not allowed here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per error it's clear Oracle is not allowing to do
Subqueries in CHECK constraints.

This is doable by JOIN.

```
ALTER TABLE abonnement ADD CONSTRAINT montant_inclus CHECK(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM service WHERE service.prix = abonnement.montant));
```

It's also possible using Trigger and other ways.

1. [similar question answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071024/using-subquery-in-a-check-statement-in-oracle)
2. [how to add constraint via trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087859/select-in-a-check-with-a-trigger?noredirect=1&lq=1)